# vector iterator parameter as template C++

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

```
template<typename T>
void Merge_Sort(vector<T>::iterator begin, vector<T>::iterator end) {

size_t length = end - begin;
if (1 >= length) return;

size_t mid = length/2;

Merge_Sort(begin, begin + mid);
Merge_Sort(begin + mid, end);
inplace_merge(begin, begin + mid, end);
}
```

I am trying to template-ize the function but getting the error that I am missing the typename prior to vector::iterator. Could anybody have an idea about making this function template?

To sum, I am trying to make iterator parameter as template.

Comment: `typename` may be handy for this problem, but why not just make the iterator the template parameter itself. (or was that the point, sorry if I misunderstood).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `std::distance`, `std::next` (or std::advance in c++03) to do the calculations.

Also, hardcoding `vector` is quite the opposite of making it *generic*, IYAM

```
template<typename It>
void Merge_Sort(It begin, It end) {
    size_t length = std::distance(begin, end);
    if (1 >= length) return;

    size_t mid = length/2;

    auto pivot = std::next(begin, mid);

    Merge_Sort(begin, pivot);
    Merge_Sort(pivot, end);
    inplace_merge(begin, pivot, end);
}
```

For completeness, here's one that integrates the Comparison predicate and sorts in descending order **[live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=207206d0b640c2a9a3bbc1c72489fa1d-bff069f172c3f5c3bc4a5e28d7ac9796)**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

template<typename It, 
    typename Cmp = typename std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type> >
void Merge_Sort(It begin, It end, Cmp cmp = Cmp()) {
    size_t length = std::distance(begin, end);
    if (length<2) return;

    size_t mid = length/2;

    auto pivot = std::next(begin, mid);

    Merge_Sort(begin, pivot, cmp);
    Merge_Sort(pivot, end, cmp);
    std::inplace_merge(begin, pivot, end, cmp);
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v { 1,3,7,-3,4,99,-13 };

    Merge_Sort(begin(v), end(v), std::greater<int>());

    for(auto i : v)
        std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

Comment: ..and +1 for `std::next()` (I'm always learning something new; thanks!). Shouldn't there be commas in those?

Comment: Have added the comparator and a test/demo program [live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=207206d0b640c2a9a3bbc1c72489fa1d-bff069f172c3f5c3bc4a5e28d7ac9796)

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer. I am new to C++. Would you be kind enough to provide a link on what you have done with the second template argument?? (I have never seen something like that before)

Comment: @GregorWattersHärtl It's another type argument that allows the caller to specify a comparator type. The `= ...` story specifies a default value. It's a little bit complex because we have to deduce the value-type of the iterator range (using `iterator_traits` in this example). Since c++14 we can simplify using [`less<void>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_void) so it would be much more straightforward: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5eca1407239a8f2, also note the default isn't used in the example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4694f8475964e41

Comment: @sehe oh wow thank you so much for the explanation!! I'll read up on that right now. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't just hammer this out. I had it in an old source file, but I think this was what you were trying to do. I've added two additional interfaces for sorting fixed arrays and arbitrary based-pointers with a specified length. Hope it helps:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

// general mergesort algorithm
template <
  typename Iterator,
  typename Compare=std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>
>
void mergesort(Iterator first, Iterator last, const Compare& cmp=Compare())
{
    size_t n = std::distance(first, last)/2;
    if (n == 0)
        return;

    Iterator mid = std::next(first, n);
    mergesort(first, mid, cmp);
    mergesort(mid, last, cmp);
    std::inplace_merge(first, mid, last, cmp);
}

// front-loader for static arrays
template<typename Item, size_t N>
void mergesort(Item (&ar)[N])
{
    mergesort(std::begin(ar), std::end(ar));
}

// front-loader for size-specified base-pointer arrays
template<typename Item>
void mergesort(Item *ptr, size_t N)
{
    mergesort(ptr, ptr+N);
}
```

Comment: Ha, I _did_ just hammer it out, and I didn't assume random-access iterators. Hmm. Perhaps inplace_merge requires them anyways ... :|

Comment: @sehe lol. I never really checked, this was back when I was exploring the fun side of `iterator_traits<>` (which f'ing *rocks*, btw).

Comment: +1 for actually including a comparator

Answer (score 1):

> getting the error that I am missing the typename prior to vector::iterator

As the error says, you're missing `typename` before `vector<T>::iterator`:

```
void Merge_Sort(typename vector<T>::iterator begin, typename vector<T>::iterator end)
                ^^^^^^^^                            ^^^^^^^^
```

This is needed when specifying a *dependent type name*: the name of a type nested in a template, that depends on the template arguments. Until the template is instantiated, the compiler doesn't know what the name represents, so you must tell it that it names a type.

> To sum, I am trying to make iterator parameter as template.

Then it might be better to do just that:

```
template <typename Iter>
void Merge_Sort(Iter begin, Iter end);
```

Comment: Thanks!!!! But could anybody know why I do not have to put anything like Merge_Sort<int> when I actually call this function? Is it because it is NOT class template, but function template? I remember reading something like this in textbook but I can't find it now.

Comment: Yes, it's because it's a function template. It's called "template argument deduction" - if the template arguments can be deduced from the types of the function arguments, then you don't have to give the template arguments.